# Login through facebook appends some codes to redirect url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using **facebook-php-sdk** for user authentication to my website. I am able to redirect to facebook for login. After login it redirects to my specified location. Till here everything works fine. But when facebook redirects it appends some code to my redirect_url like

```
http://website_url/page.php#access_token=somecode&expires_in=somenumber&state=somecode
```

And I am not able to handle this. My server shows error `500-Internal Server Error` But when I manually delete these extra things from URL, then it works fine and I am able to access user's information.

I have seen this post at facebook [Facebook Login Flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/) . But not able to understand the topic **Inspecting access tokens**

> *Please provide me solution to handle these extra things in my url.*
>
> *How can I redirect without these access token*

Answer (score 0):

You can try just ignore that's strings. 
Maybe with .htaccess using CacheIgnoreQueryString On

You may want to look:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheignorequerystring

If you use a Windows Server, check if UrlScan is enabled. In many cases, symbols such % cause error 500.